# Making 3d block from flat 2d polygon in ArcScene?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene

I would like to make a mountain from flat polygon (this polygon is the base contour of the mountain). The question is how to make it keeping 35 angle of the slope ? The top of the mountain should be flat (no cone). At the end I would like to make calculation of the volume.

I'm new in ArcScene.

[image]

Comment: You need to define elevation of the plateau or better difference in elevations to get a solution

Answer (score 4):

The workflow to get this:

[image]

- Elevation of original buffer = 100m.
- I defined plateau elevation = 150 m, and computed D=50/tan(35).
  D=71.40 m.
- Next - create negative buffer "outside only" with minus 71.40 m.
- Converted inner ring to polyline and populated new field Z=150.
- Convert original buffer to polyline and populate new field by 100.
  Used 2 polylines and original buffer to create TIN.

Tin can be converted to triangles if you want to, volume is also easy to find through 3D tools.

Note that you'll have artefacts (flat areas) in the image unless your polygon <> it's own convex hull. There is also a limit to top elevation